# Extract XML Multiple Namespace with XSL

Tags: xslt, extract

I have this XML with namespace and i need to extract on segment "NewDataSet"
I have  a xsl code but it's not works

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Listado_OrdenesResponse xmlns='http://tempuri.org/' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' 
xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
 <Listado_OrdenesResult>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1' xmlns:msdata='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata'>
   <NewDataSet xmlns=''>
    <RowNum diffgr:id='RowNum1' msdata:rowOrder='0'>
     <MATNR>10000101</MATNR>         <AUFNR>731200000047</AUFNR>
     <MENGE>385</MENGE>
     <MEINS>G</MEINS>
    </RowNum>
    <RowNum diffgr:id='RowNum2' msdata:rowOrder='1'>
     <MATNR>45000528</MATNR>
     <AUFNR>731200000047</AUFNR>
     <MENGE>540</MENGE>
     <MEINS>KG</MEINS>
    </RowNum>
   </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
 </Listado_OrdenesResult>
</Listado_OrdenesResponse>
```

I need to extract like this segment , NewDataSet.

```html
<NewDataSet> <RowNum>
    <MATNR>10000101</MATNR>
     <AUFNR>731200000047</AUFNR>
    </RowNum>
   <RowNum>
     <MATNR>45000528</MATNR>
     <AUFNR>731200000047</AUFNR>
    </RowNum>
   </NewDataSet>
<!-- Need To Extract -->
```

I have this code but the return is not as expected.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2018 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="//NewDataSet">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I run the above XSL, I got this XML.
I will have the segment without namespace

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RowNum xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
        xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        diffgr:id="RowNum1"
        msdata:rowOrder="0">
     <MATNR>10000101</MATNR>
     <AUFNR>731200000047</AUFNR>
     <MENGE>385</MENGE>
     <MEINS>G</MEINS>
    </RowNum>
<RowNum xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
        xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata"
        xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        diffgr:id="RowNum2"
        msdata:rowOrder="1">
     <MATNR>45000528</MATNR>
     <AUFNR>731200000047</AUFNR>
     <MENGE>540</MENGE>
     <MEINS>KG</MEINS>
    </RowNum>
```

Can you Help me?

Comment: The first segment you have has fewer elements than the segment (i.e. the first does not have `MENGE` or `MEINS`) so it is not quite clear what you want, whether you want to have all the child elements of a `RowNum` or only certain ones like `MATNR` and `AUFNR`.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 2.0, use `<xsl:copy-of select="XXXX" copy-namespaces='no'/>`.

In XSLT 1.0 you need to use a variant of the identity template, copying elements using `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="namespace-uri()"/>`.

Please don't ask XSLT questions without saying which version you are using, as many things are easier with XSLT 2.0 or 3.0!